# как перейти на другую страницу через переменную в андроид

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно реализовать переход на другую страницу через переменную "web" это нужно из-за того что я создал несколько меню через RecyclerView и для каждой нужна своя отдельная кнопка

```
//код модели
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView , GameRecycler;
CaregoryAdapter caregoryAdapter;
static GameAdapter gameAdapter;
static List<com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game> gameList = new ArrayList<>();
static List<com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game> fullgameList = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    categoryList.add(new Category(1 ,"Math"));
    categoryList.add(new Category(2 ,"Test"));
    categoryList.add(new Category(3 ,"Name"));
    categoryList.add(new Category(4 ,"Logics"));

    setCategoryRecycler(categoryList);


    gameList.add(new com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game(1 ,3 , "map"
            , "Name " , "12 жовтня", "3" ,
            "#424345" ,
            "Take a quiz to test your knowledge of the names of famous landmarks from around the world" ,
            "activity_color"));
    gameList.add(new com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game(2 ,4 , "brain" , "IQ " , "12 жовтня", "3" , "#424345" , "Take an IQ test and find out the result in just 10-20 minutes" , "http://omc.univ.kiev.ua/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%96%d1%97/"));
    gameList.add(new com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game(3 ,2 , "test" , "Test" , "12 жовтня", "5" , "#424345" , "In this mode, all the knowledge of the application is collected, spend it and find out how well you studied" , "http://omc.univ.kiev.ua/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%96%d1%97/"));
    gameList.add(new com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game(4 ,1 , "math" , "Math" , "12 жовтня", "3" , "#424345" , "The easiest way to test your knowledge in the field of mathematics, several tasks will show what you are capable of" , "http://omc.univ.kiev.ua/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%96%d1%97/"));

    fullgameList.addAll(gameList);

    setGameRecycler(gameList);

}

private void setGameRecycler(List<com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game> gameList) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);

    GameRecycler = findViewById(R.id.GameRecycler);
    GameRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    gameAdapter = new GameAdapter(this, gameList);
    GameRecycler.setAdapter(gameAdapter);
}

private void setCategoryRecycler(List<Category> categoryList) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    caregoryAdapter = new CaregoryAdapter(this, categoryList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(caregoryAdapter);

}
public static void ShowGameByCategory(int categories){

    gameList.clear();
    gameList.addAll(fullgameList);


    List<com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game> filterNews = new ArrayList<>();

    for (com.example.iqtest.ui.home.model.Game n : gameList) {
        if(n.getNews() == categories)
            filterNews.add(n);

    }
    gameList.clear();
    gameList.addAll(filterNews);

    gameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

```
//Основная активити
public class GamePage extends AppCompatActivity {
String weeb ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_page);

    ConstraintLayout newsBg = findViewById(R.id.GameBG);
    ImageView newsImage = findViewById(R.id.GameImage);
    TextView newsTitle = findViewById(R.id.GameTitle);
    TextView newsDate = findViewById(R.id.newspageDate);
    TextView newsPoint = findViewById(R.id.newspagepoint);
    TextView newsText = findViewById(R.id.newsPageText);


    newsBg.setBackgroundColor(getIntent().getIntExtra("newsBg" , 0));
    newsImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("newsimage",0));
    newsTitle.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("newstitle"));
    newsDate.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("newsdate"));
    newsPoint.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("newspoint"));
    newsText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("newstext"));
    String web = (getIntent().getStringExtra("Web"));

    weeb = web;

}

public void Web(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),weeb.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

[image: Ошибка кода]

[image: Часть куда вводятся переменные]

Comment: Вам стоит исправить вопрос и код. Во первых - код надо показывать текстом, не картинкой - текст можно скопировать, чтобы показать нужные исправления, а с картинки придётся переписывать, что в разы снижает вероятность получить ответ. Также вам надо разобраться с правилами именования в Java - что с большой буквы, а что - с маленькой. Ну и, наверное, научиться отличать методы от переменных. В коде у вас никакой переменной `web` не видно. Скорее всего вам надо что-то типа передачи аргументов в активити через Bundle через Intent. Но не факт, т.к. суть проблемы не вполне ясна

Comment: А что, собственно, передаётся в эту переменную?

Comment: в переменную должно передаваться название активити , изначально туда передавалась ссылка на сайты с детальной информацией , но планы изменились и теперь нужно передавать активити